# Confused by jpa exam on transactions and locking

Tags: java, exception, jpa-2.0

Follow source is given:

```
public void create ()
{
  try {
   doA () {
 } catch (PersistenceException e) {}
   try (doB) ();
 } catch (PersistenceException e) {} 
}
```

Calling method doA will cause an NonUniqueResultException to be thrown.
Calling method doB will cause an EntityExistsException to be thrown.
What two options describe what will happen when the created method is called within an application, uses container managed transactions? (Choose two):

- A. Method `doB()` will never be called.
- B. The current transaction will continue after `doA()` executes.
- C. The current transaction will continue after `doB()` executes.
- D. The current transaction will be marked for rollback when `doA()` is called.
- E. The current transaction will be marked for rollback when `doB()` is called.

In my view the correct answers are B,E.

Comment: I think it should be C. But I'm not that sure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a question "on transactions and locking", it's a question on semantics of JPA exceptions:

- `NonUniqueResultException` doesn't need to mark the current transaction for rollback, because it doesn't cause any damage to the persistence context
- `EntityExistsException` marks the current transaction for rollback, because it indicates a serious inconsistency between persistence context and the database.

  Also note that this exception may be caused by a database constraint failure during commit - in that case transaction would be rolled back anyway, therefore semantics of the excepion should guarantee rollback in all cases.

Thus, B,E is the correct answer.

Also see their Javadocs: [`NonUniqueResultException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/NonUniqueResultException.html), [`EntityExistsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityExistsException.html).

Answer (score 5):

Assuming syntactically correct version:

```
public void create() {
    try {
        doA ();
    } catch (PersistenceException e) {}
    try {
        doB();
    } catch (PersistenceException e) {}
}
```

*A. Method doB() will never be called* is **false** claim, because thrown NonUniqueResultException, which is extends PersistenceException is caught and next step in flow is to call doB().

*B. The current transaction will continue after doA() executes* is **true**, because as documented, [NonUniqueResultException](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/NonUniqueResultException.html) does not cause transaction to be marked for rollback.

*C. The current transaction will continue after doB() executes* is **false**, because [EntityExistsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityExistsException.html) marks active transaction for rollback.

*D. The current transaction will be marked for rollback when doA() is called* this is **false** because of reason told for claim B, NonUniqueResultException does not mark transaction for rollback.

*E. The current transaction will be marked for rollback when doB() is called* is **true**, because of reason told for claim C, EntityExistsException marks transaction for rollback.